# Prove the convergence of a sequence based on sub-sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that every convergent sub-sequence of $a_n$ converges to zero. Prove that $a_n$ converges to zero.

I tried to prove this statement using the definition of limit. From the question, I know that $a_{n_k}$ converges to zero $\forall$ k $\in$ N. I want to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in$ natural number such that $\forall n > N$, we have |$a_n - 0$| $< \epsilon$

Comment: What if $a_{2n}=0$ and $a_{2n+1}=2n+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $(a_{n})$ must be bounded, if not, one can find some $|a_{n_{k}}|$ such that $|a_{n_{k}}|\rightarrow\infty$, if your convergence includes the sort of infinity, then this violates the assumption.

Now let a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n_{k}}|=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|$, so by assumption $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|=0$. Hence $0\leq\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|\leq\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|=0$ and we have then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_{n}|=0$.

Answer (score 1):

What about the sequence, $$1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,....$$

Here every convergent sub-sequence goes to $0$ but the sequence does not converge.

If you do not like too many zeros, then consider

$$ 1,1/2,-1/2,2, 1/3,-1/3, 3,1/4,-1/4,4,.....$$